# Unique Count in Pandas with a Condition

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

above is the data frame from which i need to get the count of account id transacted newly in the month of may

Condition for New Account: those account which has not transacted in last 3 months

Highlighted cell is the new Account from which i need only distinct count of account id

Desired Output

[image]

using pandas python

Comment: Hi, you could add what you have tried in order to get better feedback

Comment: i had tried pivot table to get the distinct count and if condition in excel,but now the data is huge and cant be handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @tlouarn's answer, drop_duplicates() first and then use agg('count')

```
month = 'May'                    # pick the desired Month
mdf = df[df['Month'] == month]   # rows of May
odf = df.iloc[:max(mdf.index)]   # rows before June
odf = odf.drop_duplicates(       # remove duplicates
        subset=[
            'Acc ID',
            ], keep='first')
odf = odf[odf['Month'] == month] # keep rows of May
ndf = odf.groupby(               # thanks to @tlouarn
        by=['Month']             
        ).agg([
            'count'
            ])
print(ndf)
```

assume that the dataframe is sorted on Month.

Comment: this gives the unique count of account id for each month, I need to find the count of unique  account id transacted in month may which had not transacted FEB,MAR,APR

Answer (score 0):

I would use `drop_duplicates(subset=['Acc ID', 'Month'])` to filter out the duplicates, then use a `groupby(by=['Month']).agg(['count'])` to get to the desired output.